# How to compile so that filenames / line numbers are available for error-reporting tool?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, error-reporting, pdb-files, steam

I have a game that is sold on Steam, and as such uses the Steamworks SDK. This has an automatic error-collecting tool [as described briefly here](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/developmenttools.php).

Every time my game generates an unhandled exception, it is logged on the tool's web site. I've noticed that when the crash occurs on MY development build, the logged crash includes filenames and line numbers. However, when the crash occurs on a user machine, this info is absent.

- Is this probably because I have the PDBs on my machine but not the user's machine?
- Are there any compilation flags that might bake limited information into the EXE, so that the error reporting tool might be able to grab it?

I realize this is a bit of a longshot question and asked in relation to a specific tool. I asked because I'm hoping there is general knowledge (about compilation flags, etc) which I can apply to my specific situation.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `/Z7` which embeds debug information instead of producing a PDB?

Comment: Having debug info shouldn't affect the logging level of any exception throwal **unless** the source code is specifically instructed to "reduce verbosity" in a release build (e.g. ifdefs for debug builds). It is often undesirable in production quality products to expose filenames, line numbers or source level information and thus the info is either obfuscated (e.g. printing out a bitshift combination of file ID, line number and some other stuff you need to diagnose the crash) or completely removed. I never used Steamworks and anyway you would have to take a look at its source code to verify it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Steamworks SDK, but will at least try to explain common usage of preprocessor `NDEBUG`, `_DEBUG`, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` on classic `assert.h` (taken from Windows SDK / VC include):

```
#include <crtdefs.h>

#undef  assert

#ifdef  NDEBUG

#define assert(_Expression)     ((void)0)

#else

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

_CRTIMP void __cdecl _wassert(_In_z_ const wchar_t * _Message, _In_z_ const wchar_t *_File, _In_ unsigned _Line);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )

#endif  /* NDEBUG */
```

**Release Build** usually disables asserts by defining `NDEBUG` while **Debug Build** usually leave `NDEBUG` undefined (to enable asserts) and include `_DEBUG` for additional checks (while ***Work Build*** may have both undefined). Look at the definition of assert:

```
#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) \
  || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), \
    _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )
```

***If everything else fails*** (defining/undefining `NDEBUG` / `_DEBUG`) **you can use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` yourself** - to include that in whatever message string you are passing to the engine (or to those exceptions you may throw).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to presume you export code in Release Mode in Visual Studio, as opposed to Debug.

Visual Studio removes (by optimizing) some debugging elements, such as Memory Logging (_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks), but I am not an expert in what it does and doesn't remove. I would start with the link below, which covers debugging in release mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz.aspx